# Python 2 list comprehension and eval

Tags: python, lambda, eval, list-comprehension

How do you have a multiple line statement in either a list comprehension or eval?

I was trying to turn this code:

```
def f(x, y, b=''):
    for i in x:
        if i in y:
            y.remove(i)
            i *= 2
        b += i
    return b
```

Into a lambda function like so:

```
j=lambda x,y:''.join(eval('y.remove(i);i*2')if i in y else i for i in x)
```

In both `x` is a string such as `'onomatopoeia'` and `y` is a list such as `['o','a','o']`.

But for some reason, it returns a syntax error. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: what are values of `x` and `y` ?

Comment: I believe lambdas are intentionally limited to single line to improve readability and clarity. You could do try converting that function into lambda, but it's a bit counter-pythonic.

Comment: `eval` requires a expression, whereas `y.remove(i);i*2` is a statement. `eval('1;1')` produces a `SyntaxError` as well.

Comment: why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: what is expected output ?? `oonoomaatopoeia` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? According to [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)  very first rule: `Beautiful is better than ugly.`

Comment: perhaps he is looking for a beautiful way to do this using a lambda

Comment: @Vivek Sable Yes, exactly

Comment: I agree with the others that you shouldn't ever do that, but if you do, at least don't use eval. You can simply use `y.pop(y.index(i)) + i` or alternatively `2 * y.pop(y.index(i))` instead of your eval call. As a side note, I doubt you're interested in performance but the algorithm is rather inefficient as you remove all elements of the list one by one; a faster alternative would be to use a `collections.Counter` and decrease the counts of the letters.

Comment: `lambda x, y, b='': reduce(lambda c, i: c + ((lambda i: (lambda dummy: i*2)(y.remove(i)))(i) if i in y else i) , x, b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably shouldn't rewrite this with a lambda because of the side-effects in the loop. If you really want to anyway, don't use an eval.

I'd suggest:

```
j = lambda x, y: ''.join((y.remove(i) or 2 * i) if i in y else i for i in x)
```

Because the result of remove is `None` the second argument to `or` will be the result. This avoids the eval. But it's still worse then a for-loop.

---

As noted in comments on the original question, `2 * y.pop(y.index(i))` is more readable than the `or` construct. You'll loop twice over `y`, but performance doesn't seem the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would vastly prefer your function but this will do what you want.

```
from itertools import chain
j = lambda x, y: ''.join(filter(None,chain.from_iterable((i * 2,y.remove(i)) if i in y else i for i in x)))

print(j("'onomatopoeia'",['o','a','o']))
'oonoomaatopoeia'
```

Comment: Why not simply `''.join(2 * y.pop(y.index(i)) if i in y else i for i in x)`?

Comment: @l4mpi, because I am using the OP's own code, also indexing has a cost so not really better than just filtering. I would use neither approach if it was up to me

Comment: I agree that neither is really the way to go, but the `pop` variant is way more readable IMO. I doubt that speed is an issue, and if it is then eliminating the `remove` call completely would probably be the best course of action (e.g. using a `Counter` and decreasing letter counts).

Comment: @l4mpi,  as I said I was using the code the OP provided and getting it to work as provided not providing a way I would ever use personally. `''.join(2 * y.pop(y.index(i)) if i in y else i for i in x)` is not something I would use either

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write good functional expressions (using `lambda`s, `map`, `reduce`, `filter` and so on), you should avoid side effects.

I would strongly prefer your code as a function rather than a lambda with side effects.

This is a sideeffect-free implementation in one lambda expression:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> (lambda x, y: reduce(lambda a, b: \
...     (a[0]+2*b, a[1][:a[1].index(b)]+a[1][a[1].index(b)+1:]) if b in a[1] \
...     else (a[0]+b, a[1]), x, ('',y))[0])('onomatopoeia', ['o','a','o'])
'oonoomaatopoeia'
```

I'm afraid it's not *short* nor *beautiful* nor *easy to understand* * as one would want it to be for a lambda. `:/` (hopefully someone can suggest an improvement)

Just a counter-example to discourage the use of a lambda in this context.

IMHO the biggest problem with lambdas in python is that there is no `where` syntax like in Standard ML to define variable aliases in the same expression. So, things get ugly pretty quick for anything non trivial.

---

If you are interested in understanding what it does, the idea is to use reduce to run an automata, where the result (at each step) is the "state" of the computation.

The initial "state" is `('', ['o','a','o'])`, and the reduce function will do the replacement as needed, starting from `'onomatopoeia'`.

This is the evolution of the "state":

```
( '',     ['o','a','o'] )    'o'
( 'oo',       ['a','o'] )    'n'
( 'oon',      ['a','o'] )    'o'
( 'oonoo',        ['a'] )    'm'
( 'oonoom',       ['a'] )    'a'
( 'oonoomaa',        [] )    't'
( 'oonoomaat',       [] )    'o'
( 'oonoomaato',      [] )    'p'
( 'oonoomaatop',     [] )    'o'
( 'oonoomaatopo',    [] )    'e'
( 'oonoomaatopoe',   [] )    'i'
( 'oonoomaatopoei',  [] )    'a'
( 'oonoomaatopoeia', [] )
```

and we take only first element of the last state.