# temporary variables in a python expression

Tags: python, functional-programming, temporary

Some (many? all?) functional programming languages like [StandardML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) and [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)) have a type of expression in the form `let ... in ...` where is possible to create temporary variables with the scope of the expression itself.

Example: `let a=b*c in a*(a+1)`

It seems that in Python there is no expression construct similar to this.

**Motivation:**

For example the body of a `lambda` function must be a (one) expression. Not two expressions. Not a statement (an assignment is a statement and not an expression).

Moreover, when writing functional expressions and in general *one-liners* in python, things can become messy pretty easily (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986215/python-2-list-comprehension-and-eval/30987008#30987008) to [Python 2 list comprehension and eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986215/python-2-list-comprehension-and-eval)).

The point of such a construct is to avoid repetition (which sometimes leads to re-computation), for example `l[:l.index(a)]+l[l.index(a)+1:]` instead of an hypothetic `let i=l.index(a) in l[:i]+l[i+1:]`

---

How can we achieve a similar language feature in python2 / python3?

Comment: What's wrong with `a=b*c; a*(a+1)`? It will have a larger scope than just the expression, of course, but that shouldn't be a problem if your code is reasonably structured and your variables reasonably named.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 two things are "wrong" with that: 1) that's actually two expressions, not one  2) the scope is not the expression `a*(a+1)`, but the scope where the expression is contained in

Comment: And now I don't understand what's wrong with those two things. :( I don't see any sort of pitfall with having two expressions instead of one, and I acknowledged the larger scope but noted that it shouldn't cause issues. Python programmers save references to variables very frequently, often with perfectly acceptable results.

Comment: For instance, the body of a `lambda` expression must be a (**single**) expression. Moreover the body of a `lambda` cannot contain an assignment, which turns out to be a statement and not an expression.

Comment: If you're in a situation where you cannot do the assignment in a preceding statement for some reason, I guess you could do some hack like `lambda: [a*(a+1) for a in [b*c]][0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't really idiomatic code, but for single expressions you can use lambdas that you immediately invoke. Your example would look like this:

```
>>> b, c = 2, 3
>>> (lambda a: a * (a + 1))(b * c)
42
```

You can also write this using keyword arguments if that helps readability:

```
>>> (lambda a: a * (a + 1))(a=b * c)
42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of simulate a smaller scope for your temporary variable by putting it into an iterable and then looping over that iterable:

```
>>> b,c = 2,3
>>> var = [a*(a+1) for a in [b*c]][0]
>>> var
42
```

This puts the single value `b*c` into a `list`, then loops over that `list` in a comprehension, with each new value consisting of some transformation of each element. The created `list` is one element in length, and we get the first element in it with `[0]`. Without the comprehension, it looks as follows:

```
>>> b,c = 2,3
>>> var = []
>>> for a in [b*c]:
...     var.append(a*(a+1))
...
>>> var = var[0]
>>> var
42
```